# Is it possible to play Counter Strike on Fedora?

Tags: linux, fedora

How can I play Counter-Strike on Fedora33 without wine?
I've found several ways of doing that, but all of them are with wine. Can you help, please?

Comment: This game under Linux does not **feel** the same as under Windows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Enable third party repositories. *Software* will ask for that on the first start, you can do it also later from the *Software repositories* menu. Make sure the *RPM Fusion for Fedora 33 - Nonfree - Steam* repository is *Enabled*.

   [image]

   [image]
2. Install Steam. Either using the "Software" tool or with `sudo dnf install steam`
3. Open Steam and install Counter Strike, wine is not needed, both the "original" CS and CS:GO run natively on Linux.

Nice howto for installing Steam for Fedora with screenshots is available on [FOSS Linux](https://www.fosslinux.com/41353/how-to-install-steam-and-enable-proton-on-fedora.htm).